# What does 'meet the sales' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

I've been reading an article and stumbled upon this paragraph:
'How can an iOS and android app meet the sales? What about other platforms and individuals using those devices?'

What does 'meet the sales' mean? I've tried using online translators, but it still doesn't make sense

Comment: It sounds like an incomplete sentence, 'sales targets' perhaps.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. uhm.. I see, it kind of does

Comment: Please link the article so we can see the context.

Comment: @StuartF ok. Here it is: https://medium.com/@Cubet_Techno_Labs/flutter-with-progressive-web-app-support-flutter-pwa-7b37752efbaa                          P. S. : you can use Ctrl + F to find the needed piece of text in the article

Comment: @Coder4Fun250, it's far better for you to quote the relevant text within the question rather than expecting everyone that reads the question to have to do that search, especially so when a year from now that link no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

> "*it still doesn't make sense*"

Are you saying that the rest of that page *did* make sense?

From my cursory reading, it is all market-speak; words and phrases that sound impressive, but which, when one rereads and thinks about them, don't actually mean much of anything.

This one really isn't worth worrying about.